# adding rollover menu to images on page

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

I have 3 images inline. They are stored in span tags with class imgAvatar
Above them there are 3 identical images ( delete buttons menu ) which are hidden from the beginning.
these are stored in spans with class imgAvatarSelector.

Css of delete buttons

```
.imgAvatarDelButtons {
    display: none;
  /*  height:50px; */
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="Line1">
            <span id="imgAvatarSelector1" number="1" class="imgAvatarSelector"><img id="imgAvatarDel1" number="1" class="imgAvatarDelButtons " src="/img/del-50.png" style="display: none;"><span id="imgAvatar1" number="1" class="imgAvatar"><img src="/files/test1/178131u7r-240.jpg"></span></span>
            <span id="imgAvatarSelector2" number="2" class="imgAvatarSelector"><img id="imgAvatarDel2" number="2" class="imgAvatarDelButtons " src="/img/del-50.png" style="display: none;"><span id="imgAvatar2" number="2" class="imgAvatar"><img src="/files/test1/1de726eii-240.jpg"></span></span>
            <span id="imgAvatarSelector3" number="3" class="imgAvatarSelector"><img id="imgAvatarDel3" number="3" class="imgAvatarDelButtons " src="/img/del-50.png" style="display: none;"><span id="imgAvatar3" number="3" class="imgAvatar"><img src="/files/test1/z5fdaz034-240.jpg"></span></span>
        </div>
```

script which shows and hides delete buttons

```
$('.imgAvatarSelector').mouseover(function() {

    $('#imgAvatarDel'+$(this).attr('number')).show();
});

$('.imgAvatarSelector').mouseout(function() {
    $('#imgAvatarDel'+$(this).attr('number')).hide();
});
```

Now when I rollover mouse over images, first time all delete buttons are shown correctly above images. then after mouseOUT they hide. But next time you rollover them, only first one shows back correctly the same place. Second and third delete buttons are shown below the whole this line of images to the start left.

Anything to fix in CSS or use different jquery function ?

**UPDATE**
In JSFidle my example works OK.
But in my application something is different. Second del button act like it wants to be div and starts from new line.
http://jsfiddle.net/vasuydwh/

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the whole css that effects del button 
[image]

**UPDATE 3**

ACtually I have 3 lines there in 3 divs. And each lines first del button only works OK. others tend to appear on the next line. So it's something with divs probably. But still cannot understand what exactly

Comment: can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net? it would be much easier to help you :)

Comment: better avoid `number="1"` make it as `data-number="1"` and get id in jquery by `$(this).data('number')` .

Comment: yes, in js fiddle its work fine. Maybe other css rules affected there. Need to show full code then it will be easier to debug who/where affected?

Comment: I've updated question, added screen of the whole css that effects del button, please have a look.

Comment: Fixed problem myself. No need for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use css insted of javascript to show delete buttons.
All you need to do is deleate all js for showing "delete buttons", add this css and test it.

```
.imgAvatarSelector:hover .imgAvatarDelButtons{
    display: block; /*OR inline, inline-block*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css selectors instead, removing the need for jQuery altogether:

```css
#Line1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  position: relative;
}
#Line1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
#Line1:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Line1">
  <span id="imgAvatarSelector1" number="1" class="imgAvatarSelector"><img id="imgAvatarDel1" number="1" class="imgAvatarDelButtons " src="/img/del-50.png" style="display: none;"><span id="imgAvatar1" number="1" class="imgAvatar"><img src="/files/test1/178131u7r-240.jpg"></span></span>
  <span id="imgAvatarSelector2" number="2" class="imgAvatarSelector"><img id="imgAvatarDel2" number="2" class="imgAvatarDelButtons " src="/img/del-50.png" style="display: none;"><span id="imgAvatar2" number="2" class="imgAvatar"><img src="/files/test1/1de726eii-240.jpg"></span></span>
  <span id="imgAvatarSelector3" number="3" class="imgAvatarSelector"><img id="imgAvatarDel3" number="3" class="imgAvatarDelButtons " src="/img/del-50.png" style="display: none;"><span id="imgAvatar3" number="3" class="imgAvatar"><img src="/files/test1/z5fdaz034-240.jpg"></span></span>
</div>
```